# Something appear on android emulator when press CTRL+M

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to enable hot reload when develop an android app, then I press **CTRL+M** on my emulator, but this thing also appear on my emulator screen.
I don't know what is therm for this thing, but I want to hide that.

[image]

So, my question is, what is therm for that thing and what are the keyboard shortcuts to hide that..?

Answer (score 3):

You can use pinch action in emulator while holding the `ctrl` and dragging the mouse. (this is used for zoom in and zoom out). This should be some glitch that happens because of stuck your pc. Restarting the emulator should remove this.